# Vue Mixin properties are blank/empty/not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I hope this question is not a duplicate. If it is so, please point me to the right directions.

I have a Vue application which is compiled with Webpack@NPM. I use mixin to propagate a property (`roles`) across all components. I update it with an ajax call from app instantiation. Problem is `roles` only updates for the `<Root>` component, not for all others.

```
////////////////////////
// app.js
////////////////////////

// import
window.axios = require('axios')
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes.js'

// mixin
Vue.mixin({
    data: function () {
        return {

            // property in question
            roles: [],
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getRoles: function() { //////////// this method updates property.
            // get
            axios.get('/api/vcr/admin/roles')

            // process
            .then(response=>{
                this.roles = response.data.data;
            })

            // error?
            .catch(error=>{
                this.toast(error.response.data.message);
            })
        },
    },
});

// router
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes:  routes,
});

// app
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App: require('./views/App').default },
    router,
    base: '/saas/vcr/admin',

    created: function() { ////////////// I update it here
        this.getRoles();
    }
});
```

```
////////////////////////
//  Foo.vue
////////////////////////

<script>
    export default {
        mounted: function() {
            console.log(this.roles) ////// returns an empty array
        }
    }
</script>
```

Do you know how to make `roles` reactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global mixin you have created does not call the function that populates the `roles` property,  it relies on the inheriting instance to do so. In your `app` "root" instance, you're doing that in the `created` life-cycle hook which calls `getRoles` on the mixin, but in the component `Foo` you are not calling it, so it will have its default empty value. The `roles` property is not shared, each component will get its own copy of it and will need to be populated.

You could change the mixin to do this for you, by adding the life-cycle `created` hook as you have done in the root instance. [Here's](https://codepen.io/steve16351/pen/KKKEbZV?editors=1010#0) an example of that. Note implementing that in the mix-in does not prevent or override later life cycle hooks from being run on the instances it is merged into. But, it will in your case make an API call for every component instance that is created, which probably isn't desirable.

If you want to only populate it once then share it between all components, it might make more sense to use Vuex and have a global state where `roles` is populated centrally and shared between all components in a reactive way.